# Apache : SetEnv not allowed here in apache logs

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have problems to launch a web application : i get the following error :

```
C:/wamp/www/dev/htdocs/.htaccess: SetEnv not allowed here
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: RTFM: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv  the "Context" section tells you where this directive is allowed to appear. Since you've not provided an example of your .htaccess, we cannot help you, and this is the best answer you can get.

Comment: The error message is actually _very_ precise. Read it. Understand it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use SetEnv within a .htaccess file, you need to set...
`AllowOverride FileInfo`
...within the relevant virtualhost directory block. (And then restart the httpd service as per usual.)